# Como criar Queries para gerar um SCHEMA em JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Estou tentando criar uma query para criar um schema em sql automaticamente;
assim que abrir o programa ele executa: createQuery("CREATE NEW SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS BancoDeDados");

Meu projeto está assim:

-Classe EntityManagerSource

```
public class EntityManagerSource {

private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenciaDAO");

@Produces @RequestScoped
public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
    System.out.println("Banco de Dados: Conectado");
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

-Classe PERSISTENCE.XML

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenciaDAO" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>br.edu.ifma.ticketif.model.entity.database.Aluno</class>
    <class>br.edu.ifma.ticketif.model.entity.Usuario</class>
<properties>

  <!--  propriedades do servidor -->
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BancoDeDados?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useSSL=false"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

  <!--  propriedades da hibernate -->
  <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />

  <!--  Atualizações do banco de dados -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

</properties>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui apenas alterando a Persistence.xml

Usando o comando createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Ficou assim:

```
   <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BancoDeDados
              ?useTimezone=true&amp;
              serverTimezone=UTC&amp;
              useSSL=false&amp;
              createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>
```